# Laravel artisan commands work with port 33060 but database stops working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I'm working on a Laravel 5.8 project using Homestead. The project works fine with database port is set to `3306` but I can't run artisan commands. When I change database port to `33060` database stops working but artisan commands work. with port `3306` whe I run any artisan command I get this message

[image]

And when I switch to `33060` error disappears and can run artisan commands but database stops working

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1
APP_ENV=local
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=forums
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Never used Homestead myself, but check out this related question:

[Strange behaviour Laravel Homestead Database Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321121/strange-behaviour-laravel-homestead-database-connection?rq=1)

It seems that the error could be relative to whether or not you are running the commands in the VM or on your physical machine.

Comment: running artisan commands outside vagrant ssh won't work thanks for the hint. I have to run artisan commands inside vagrant ssh

Answer (score 0):

By default, a MySQL server listens to the port 3306, that's why it works. But if you wish another port, then you have to change your MySQL server setup.

[How to change the default port of mysql from 3306 to 3360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360)